# Как запустить на выполнение скрипт и не ждать ответа?

Tags: php

Как из php вызвать другой скрипт (в моем случае так же на php) и не ждать ответа. То есть запустить скрипт и все. Забыть про него и все.

Comment: А после того как другой скрипт отработает что должно произойти? Может пример того что вы делаете? А то не совсем понятно, что это и зачем.. Может достаточно `cron` запустить?

Comment: Да, про крону он и так работает раз в 30 минут. Но ещё нужно чтобы по событию (оформление заказа), выполнялся принудительная отправка заказа на МойСклад по API.

Comment: Ужасное решение. Если произойдет ошибка отправки заказа в МойСклад - то как обрабатывать эту ситуацию будете?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Cогласен. На данный момент только веду журнал. А как правильнее?

Answer (score 2):

Если есть скрипт `a.php`, в котором нужно вызвать скрипт `b.php` и не дожидаясь его окончания продолжить работу, то можно использовать [сокеты](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.sockets.php):

Пример, вызываем скрипт `b.php` и передаем в него переменную `foo` со значением `bar` (можно передать и массив и что угодно или ничего не передавать). В `b.php` берем присланное значение и записываем в файл.

Банально в `b.php` будет для простоты написано:

`file_put_contents('test.txt', $_POST['foo']);`

В файле `a.php`:

```
function exec_script($url, $params = array()) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);

    if (!$fp = fsockopen($parts['host'], isset($parts['port']) ? $parts['port'] : 80)) {
        return false;
    }

    $data = http_build_query($params, '', '&');

    fwrite($fp, "POST " . (!empty($parts['path']) ? $parts['path'] : '/') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Host: " . $parts['host'] . "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Content-Length: " . strlen($data) . "\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n");
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);

    return true;
}

exec_script('http://YOUR_HOST/b.php', array('foo' => 'bar'));
```

Comment: 1) забыл отправить запрос - fputs;
2) в b.php добавить ignore_user_abort(true), чтобы он мог жить своей жизнью, что мне и требовалось;

А так большое спасибо. Тоже в этом направлении копал, но сразу что-то не получилось.

Так же можно использовать exec и т.п, благо скрипты лежать рядом.

Comment: @Sergey вы что-то путаете.......`fputs` является псевдонимом `fwrite`, так что в примере все правильно написано...хотя можно почище написать, записав строки ПОСТ в одну переменную и потом просто написать `fwrite($fp, $query);`..... А в `b.php` пропустил да.......а можете попробовать на `jquery` написать `$.post( "get.php", {foo: "John", set: "2pm" });` :-D